# Unity detect drag to a game object

Tags: unity, mouse

I want to detect when a UI object it dragged and released on top of a game object. The drags starts on a sprite on the canvas outside of the game object. I tried using `OnMouseUp()` but it only work if the `MouseDown` event happens on the same game object. How can I detect `MouseUp` events that started outside of my object and ended inside the object.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by checking if the mouse is currently over the game object and checking if the mouse button is released inside the function

```
 void OnMouseOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMouseOver on GameObject");
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("MouseButtonUp");
        }
    }
```